# When I change the material on one eye two others switch to the same materials, the two that switch are copies of the first one, How can I fix this?

Tags: materials

- I have highlighted the eye I want to change blue and  the ones that should stay the same in yellow *
  [image]

Comment: You need to give it another material. If the eyes are linked duplications, you need to make them single user: Select and go in the Object menu > Relations > Single User > Object & Data & Material

Comment: Thank you moonboots